# MySQL both not equal to

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (a!=1 AND b!=2)
```

How can I select all rows where `a` is not `1` and `b` is not `2` in the same time?

That is - in PHP it'd be `($a!=1 && $b!=2)`, bringing rows for example like

```
a=1, b=6,
a=5, b=2,
...
```

(but not `a=1, b=2`)

What I am getting with MySQL equals to PHP's `$a!=1 && $b!=2` (the same just without brackets), bringing rows like

```
a=7, b=9,
a=4, b=0,
...
```

(but never `a=1`, and never `b=2`)

Comment: I don't think the PHP code does what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, you want `or`, not `and`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE a <> 1 OR b <> 2;
```

Although MySQL (and other databases) support `!=` for inequality, the standard is `=`.  If you want to allow `NULL` values, you might want:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE a <=> 1 OR b <=> 2;
```

`<=>` is a `NULL`-safe inequality operator specific to MySQL.